# Is there a way to get React to autodefine "keys" for children?

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning React, and I stumbled upon this quirk with "dynamic children."

Preamble with a code example:

```jsx
// Render Pass 1
<Card>
  <p>Paragraph 1</p>
  <p>Paragraph 2</p>
</Card>

// Render Pass 2
<Card>
  <p>Paragraph 2</p>
</Card>
```

In the second `render()` pass, it seems the way the vdom diffing works is that it deletes the second  child, then transforms the text in the first to say "Paragraph 2." It's fast, but you'll see weird stuff happening if you needed state to persist on say... the second  child!

So React suggests using a ["key" attribute for those  tags](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html#dynamic-children). Now the vdom diffing will be surprise-free and you'll see state getting preserved across `renders()`.

My question: is there a way to get React to set "keys" on its own rather than doing it the way they suggest?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**No, there is not.**

The default behavior of React when there are no keys specified is to use a naive approach updating components in-place, as you observed. Functionally, this is equivalent to specifying a default key according to the element's index with respect to its siblings. In your example, this would look like:

```
// Render Pass 1
<Card>
  <p key={0}>Paragraph 1</p>
  <p key={1}>Paragraph 2</p>
</Card>

// Render Pass 2
<Card>
  <p key={0}>Paragraph 2</p>
</Card>
```

That's why you see the text for the first element transformed, but as you note this is not always the optimal outcome. So why can't React use a more intelligent automatic key? The answer is that in order to do so, there are really only two options, and neither is ideal:

1. They could make certain assumptions about the structure of your app. In your short example, it's obvious to a human that the paragraphs should be matched according to their text content. But that's not necessarily true in all cases, and it's hard to extend that kind of logic to more complex scenarios with custom elements, lots of props, nested children, etc.
2. They could use a fancy general-purpose diffing algorithm, but these can be quite costly in terms of performance which React is very conscientious of. As the React [documentation on reconciliation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html#list-wise-diff) says:

   > There are many algorithms that attempt to find the minimum sets of operations to transform a list of elements. Levenshtein distance can find the minimum using single element insertion, deletion and substitution in O(n<sup>2</sup>). Even if we were to use Levenshtein, this doesn't find when a node has moved into another position and algorithms to do that have much worse complexity.

So, either way, any benefit of "automatic key assignment" comes with a set of drawbacks as well. In the end, it's not really worth it, especially considering that in most cases assigning keys manually is not really that difficult or cumbersome. From further down on that same documentation page:

> In practice, finding a key is not really hard. Most of the time, the element you are going to display already has a unique id. When that's not the case, you can add a new ID property to your model or hash some parts of the content to generate a key. Remember that the key only has to be unique among its siblings, not globally unique.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer @hopper. Yea, I suppose it's not too difficult to just write `<p key={item.id}>{item.message}</p>` everytime. I guess we can presume that the React guys think the speed benefits justify this slight inconvenience.

Comment: But what about random strings assignment at the generation of a component? Why wouldn't that be good?

Comment: not sure why react couldn't provide a simple way to generate keys explicitly. This way one would get all the benefits of having a key and human discretion, without being forced come up with something to be used as a key.

Answer (score 4):

You could call `React.Children.toArray` which auto defines keys